# Подскажите стихотворные аргументы о природе.

Tags: егэ

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие есть 4-2-х строчные, стихотворные аргументы по теме природы, для сочинения ЕГЭ С1.

Спасибо.

Comment: тема природы -много проблем, какая именно: красота, влияние на душу, единение с природой? И почему только стихотворные?

Comment: @Людмила, лучше на все. Всёравно заучиваю аргументы.  Текстовый, если так можно выразиться, аргументы я и так более или менее в запасе имею. Благодарю за развернутый ответ. Жду советов от других участников. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

1.Учись у них - у дуба, у березы.-А.Фет

2.И с каждой осенью я расцветаю вновь;

Здоровью моему полезен русский холод;

К привычкам бытия вновь чувствую любовь;

Чредой слетает сон, чредой находит голод;

Легко и радостно играет в сердце кровь,

Желания кипят – я снова счастлив, молод,Пушкин

3Когда природа вся трепещет и сияет,

Когда ее цвета ярки и горячи,

Душа бездейственно в пространстве утопает

И в неге врозь ее расходятся лучи. Толстой А.К.

Не сами ль мы своим воображеньем

Жизнь создаем, к бессмертию идя,

И мир зовем волшебным сновиденьем

Под музыку осеннего дождя!.. Фофаноф К.М.

Если проблема бережного отношения к природе, подойдёт Астафьев "Царь-рыба".Природа жива и одухотворена, наделена нравственно- карающей силой, она
способна не только защищаться, но и нести возмездие. Иллюстрацией
карающей силы служит судьба *Гоши Герцева.* Этот герой несет наказание
за высокомерный цинизм по отношению к людям и к природе. Карающая сила
распространяется не только на отдельных героев. Нарушение равновесия
несет угрозу всему человечеству, если оно не образумится в своей
намеренной или вынужденной жестокости.

«Слово о полку Игореве».Вся природа в «Слове» наделяется автором человеческими чувствами, способностью различать добро и зло. Она предупреждает русских о несчастьях, переживает с ними горе и радости.

А.П. Чехов «Степь» Егорушка, мальчик 9-ти лет, пораженный красотой степи, очеловечивает её и превращает в своего двойника: ему кажется, что степное пространство способно и страдать, и радоваться, и тосковать. Его переживания и мысли становятся не по-детски серьезными, философскими.

Л.Н..Толстой «Война и мир»
Наташа Ростова, восхищаясь красотой ночи в Отрадном, готова полететь, как птица: её окрыляет увиденное.Андрей Болконский во время поездки в Отрадное увидел старый дуб, и изменения, которые впоследствии произошли в душе героя, связаны с красотой и величием могучего дерева.

В. Астафьев «Царь-рыба»
Рыбак Утробин, поймав на крючок огромную рыбу, не в силах справиться с ней. Для того, чтобы избежать гибели, он вынужден отпустить ее на свободу. Встреча с рыбой, символизирующей нравственное начало в природе, заставляет этого браконьера пересмотреть свои представления о жизни.
                     Постижения прекрасного в природе
Ю. Яковлев «Разбуженный соловьями»
Озорного, непоседливого Селюжонка однажды в пионерском лагере разбудили соловьи. Рассердившись, с камнем в руке, он решает расправиться с птицами, но замирает, завороженный пением соловья. Что- то стронулось в душе мальчика, ему захотелось увидеть, а потом и изобразить лесного волшебника. И пусть вылепленная им из пластилина птица даже отдаленно не напоминает соловья, Селюжонок испытал животворящую силу искусства. Когда соловей снова разбудил его, он поднял с кроватей всех ребят, чтобы те тоже услышали волшебные трели. Автор утверждает, что постижение красоты в природе ведет к постижению красоты в искусстве, в себе.

Comment: @Людмила, кого можно процитировать, в аргументах о красоте и восхищении природы.

Comment: И Толстого А.К., и Чехова - смотря что подойдёт к тексту.

Comment: Пришвин "Голубая стрекоза", Шукшин "Солнце, старик и девушка"